# Combobox colour problems

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, background

I have a combobox in a styled window.
I am perfectly aware that the problem resides in the style but since is a company style and so I can't change it GLOBALLY. What I want to do is OVVERRIDE it whenever I am in need.

[image]

So as you see in the picture above the main problem is the background which is dark. And then, minor problem, it shows no caret.

The xaml is:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbOptions" Grid.Row="6" Background="White" Width="300" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" Height="20" Foreground="Black" IsEditable="False">
```

Thank you for your help
Patrick

--ADD--
I have tried that

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

but no luck!

--ADD2--
 I even changed it in code behind

```
//cmbOptions.ItemsSource = obcCategories;
for (int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
    item.Background = Brushes.White;
    item.Content = "AAA";
    ibw.cmbOptions.Items.Add(item);
}
```

but it didn't work for background but it did for foreground.

---ADD3---

[image]

---ADD4---
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just override global style in `Window` or `UserControl` where you use your `ComboBox`. See an example:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSelectedItemsWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="MainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="The first item"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="The second item"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="The third item"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

If you want to change background programatically, please see the following code:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
    for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
    {
       if (item == null)
          item = new ComboBoxItem();
       item.Background= Brushes.Green;                
       item.Content = start.ToString();
       comboBox.Items.Add(item);
       item = null;
    }            
}
```

Your code works excellently. You should just remove `cmbOptions` from `ibw.cmbOptions.Items.Add(item);` like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
    item.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    item.Content = "AAA";
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

What I have if I use your code:

[image]

**Update 1:**

It is really interesting why it is not working. Just another try:)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                
            <ComboBox Name="comboBox">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update2:**

I've made a sample for view. Hope it helps.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2062&authkey=!AFw5eVP7NrZlus0&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: Alas not working... I just put it in my xaml, on top of the file. But no change....

Comment: Thank you stepUp but I am not clear at what is the difference between my add2 code and yours. In any case it's not working.

Comment: I am sorry but as I said it doesn't work. I am having the same problem once again. For a reason that i can't understand the style can't be overriden. Neither in xaml nor in code-behind. I am sick and tired of that since I don't know what are the features that can't be changed and i don't know at what extent they can't be changed. If you see my ADD3 you will see that it's not working. Now sorry for the delay I was out of office. If you have any other idea I'd be glad to test 'em for you. Thank you in any case

Comment: I admire your tenaciousness but I think we should concentrate on WHY can't we override. So not working once again see my new add thanx.

Comment: @Patrick I've made a test project for you. Maybe it helps to you. Please, write about your resuls https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2062&authkey=!AFw5eVP7NrZlus0&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I ll be away for 2 days and then I ll test it!